# Install & run custom dotnet tool on azure devops release

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a Release pipeline that is triggered by a new version of a published dotnet core tool. The trigger works fine, but I'm unable to install and run the tool in my Tasks.

**CURRENTLY:**

Running a [Command Line Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line) results in a 401:

```
dotnet tool install -g --add-source=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/_packaging/Tools/nuget/v3/index.json MyApp
```

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/_packaging/Tools/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\h0g1c35v.eny\restore.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\h0g1c35v.eny\restore.csproj]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'myapp' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.
For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

This leads me to believe that I'm missing something here, making it more complicated than it needs to be, or thinking about this the wrong way. The tools in the feed can be installed locally, so I believe it's my release approach.

*I'm currently looking into [Personal Access Tokens (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)*

---

**PREVIOUSLY**:

If I use the **.Net Core task** and the `custom` option:

[image: List of .Net Core commands]

The logs show a malformed command passed to dotnet.exe:

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" "dotnet tool install -g --add-source=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/_packaging/Tools/nuget/v3/index.json MyApp"
```

*or*

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" "tool install -g --add-source=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/_packaging/Tools/nuget/v3/index.json MyApp"
```

I've tried varying arguments and I tend to always see the same error message:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
   * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
   * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-dotnet tool install -g --add-source=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/_packaging/Tools/nuget/v3/index.json MyApp does not exist.
   * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Comment: you should start a new question for this and accept this answer, because this is a completely new\unrelated question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your custom dotnet command is quoted and `dotnet` is repeated : `dotnet.exe" "dotnet tool install ..."` so the command is misinterpreted.

You can use the [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line) and set the `dotnet` command directly :

```
dotnet tool install -g --add-source=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org-name>/_packaging/Tools/nuget/v3/index.json MyApp
```

Comment: Great catch, thank you! I'm now getting a 401 Unauthorized error, which makes more sense with the private devops feed. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I am getting a similar issue with the custom `dotnet` command task in Azure DevOps, where providing `pack something` results in a command `dotnet.exe "pack something"` which is clearly wrong. The Powershell task does bring in the dotnet stuff indeed.

Answer (score 7):

Using the .Net Core task works perfect for us.

Since the dotnet command is quoted, you need to set tool as the command and update into arguments. NuGet credentials can be provided with NuGet Auth task if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my walkaround:

1. I firstly published my private dotnet tool nupkg file also as an universal package to the same Azure Artifacts feed.
2. I was able to then use [Universal Package task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) to download the `.nupkg` file into `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/nupkgs/`. This task will handle the authorization to Azure Artifacts feeds.

```
steps:
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Download mytool.cli.universal'
  inputs:
    downloadDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/nupkgs/'
    vstsFeed: '63d4aa2f-3ae7-4c27-8c18-aa8e3a9ff353'
    vstsFeedPackage: '916d9a27-2c07-4071-8631-377f2ac08ed7'
    vstsPackageVersion: 0.2.0
```

3. I then had the DotNetCoreCLI task to install my nupkg locally in agents.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install mytool as a dotnet tool'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'install --global mytool.CLI --add-source ./nupkgs --version 0.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the nuget authenticate task before you try to access the nuget feed